# jQuery file upload maxNumberOfFiles and getNumberOfFiles options

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery file upload and setting maxNumberOfFiles to 1.  However, it is allowing more than one file at a time.  The documentation states...

```
The maxNumberOfFiles option depends on the getNumberOfFiles option, which is defined by the UI and AngularJS implementations.
```

There is no further documentation on the subject.  getNumberOfFiles is just a function you can pass in.

Here is what I have...

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
                maxNumberOfFiles: 1,
                getNumberOfFiles: function () { return 1 }
});
```

Does anyone have the maxNumberOfFiles option working?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe `getNumberOfFiles` was only [added as an option to a recent version](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/pull/2270) of jquery.fileupload-ui.js (8.2.1).

As an alternative, you can set the option `singleFileUploads` to `false`, and in the `add` callback you can throw errors if more than one file is added.

```
var maxFiles = 1;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    singleFileUploads: false,
    url: '/uploadUrl'
}).bind('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
        var fileCount = data.files.length;
        if (fileCount > maxFiles) {
            alert("The max number of files is "+maxFiles);
            return false; 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found just using a simple counter works well enough

```
var maxFiles = 1;
var counter=0;
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: '/uploadUrl',
add: function (e, data) {
        if(counter < maxFiles){
            counter++;
  }else return false;

    }
});
```